# Angular 8 multiple targets in proxy.conf.json with context set

Tags: proxy, angular-cli

so my current configuration is as follows:

- I'm using a context array in order to group multiple paths to the same target

  ```
  const TARGET_URL1 = 'https://target-url-1.xyz';
  const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    { 
      context: [
        '/api/link1',
        '/api/link2',
      ],
      target: TARGET_URL1,
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true,
      ws: true,
    },
  ];
  ```

But right now, I need a new target for a new context path and I can't find any example on how to implement while keeping the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of implementation is to duplicate the whole object and change your context and targets:

```
const TARGET_URL1 = 'https://target-url-1.xyz';
const TARGET_URL2 = 'https://target-url-2.xyz';
   const PROXY_CONFIG = [
     { 
       context: [
         '/api/link1',
         '/api/link2',
       ],
       target: TARGET_URL1,
       secure: false,
       changeOrigin: true,
       ws: true,
     },
     { 
       context: [
         '/api/new-different-link',
       ],
       target: TARGET_URL2,
       secure: false,
       changeOrigin: true,
     },
   ];
```